# Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices. Prove that the matrix products $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices. Prove that the matrix products $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues

Down below is my attempt at this proof

1) $(AB)v = \lambda v$

2)$(AB)v - \lambda v = 0$

3) $(AB)^Tv - \lambda v = 0$

4) $(B^T A^T)v - \lambda v = 0$

5) $(B^T)(A^T v)^T - \lambda v = 0$

6) $(B^T)(v^T A) - \lambda v = 0$

7) $(B^T v^T)^T A - \lambda v = 0$

8) $vBA -\lambda v = 0$

9)$(BA)v = \lambda v$

10) therefore, we conclude that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues

Is this a proper way to prove that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues
? did I make a mistake somewhere?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can just proof AB=BA

Comment: The step from $4)$ to $5)$ is invalid, if you want to apply $^T$ again, you have to swap the order of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: How did you reach step 5 from 4? This is where you were wrong...

Comment: XcoderX $AB \ne BA$. The jump from 4 to 5 is not justified.

Comment: No one said the _eigenvectors_ would be the same. Just the _eigenvalues_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robert pointed out your mistake. Jack gave a high-level proof. Here is an elementary one.

Assume $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$. Then there exists a nonzero vector $x$ such that $ABx=\lambda x$. Now multiply both sides on the left by $B$, giving

$$BA(Bx)=\lambda Bx$$

If $Bx\neq0$, this shows that $BA$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$.

On the other hand, if $Bx=0$, then $ABx=0$, so $\lambda=0$ (since by hypothesis $ABx=\lambda x$ with $x\neq0$). From $\lambda=0$ we conclude $AB$ is not invertible. But

$$0=\det(AB)=\det A\det B=\det(BA)$$

Hence $BA$ also fails to be invertible, and thus it must have eigenvalue $0$.

This shows every eigenvalue of $AB$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$. By symmetry the converse holds, as well.

Answer (score 3):

By density, we may assume that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible. In such a case $AB$ and $BA$ are conjugated matrices, via $A^{-1}(AB)A = BA$, so they have the same characteristic polynomial and the same eigenvalues. As an alternative, $\text{Tr}(CD)=\text{Tr}(DC)$ implies that $(AB)^n$ and $(BA)^n$ have the same trace for any $n\geq 0$. In particular the power sums of the the eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ are the same, and by [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in going from $B^T A^T v$ to $(B^T)^T (A^T)^T v$.

Comment: I have made the appropriate corrections in my original post, can you double check if i made any other mistakes? i will appreciate it

Comment: Now the first mistake is going from $(AB) v$ to $(AB)^T v$.

Comment: Your whole strategy is doomed: even though $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues, the eigenvectors will not be the same in general.

Comment: I see, what if i tried using $det(AB - \lambda I)$ and using matrix algebra in order to get $det(BA - \lambda I)$? would this be a solid proof?

Comment: There is a proof along those lines for invertible $A$.

Comment: So $det(AB−\lambda I)$ would only work if $A$ and $B$ are invertible then? but we don't know if they actually are.

Comment: The elementary proof of $\det(AB-\lambda I) = \det(BA-\lambda I)$ assumes $A$ (or $B$) is invertible.  But once you have it for invertible $A$, it's true for all $A$ because these are continuous functions of $A$ and the invertible matrices are dense in all $n\times n$ matrices.